# How to use Excel Service (/Model) with Document ID enabled

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, excel-services, document-id

I'm currently running SharePoint 2016 and have Document ID service enabled.
Knew that once I enable the Document ID service, documents' URL will change from `~/DOCLIB/filename.xlsx` to `~/_layouts/15/DocIDRedir.aspx?ID=BLAH`. I was fine with that.

Recently got a new project that will have to use the Excel Service (/Model); so I followed the Microsoft documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/basic-uri-structure-and-path; the example the documentation had was : `ServerName/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Docs/Documents/sampleWorkbook.xlsx/model`

and of course I replaced the URL path with documentID URL like below  `ServerName/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=BLAH/Model` and I got "sorry, something went wrong" error.

Does anybody using both services and know how to get around the issue that I'm having or is there a way to get default URL path and still keeping the Document ID?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to update for someone out there wondering about this. It appears that the REST URL of the Excel services **only works** when Document ID service is **DISABLED**. Don't have much choice, I've decided to disable the Document ID feature. Interesting thing though, even though it is turned off - I was able to still use the URL for that was generated with DocID.